# Year Picker in popup with angular-ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a year picker using the angular-ui Bootstrap datepicker directive.

It works when it is inline, but not in the popup. Setting the options via datepicker-options doesn't matter for the popup.

See this Plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/GRqSTCE7hOP6ZbBY3dZd

Why does this datepicker:

[image: Inline year picker works]

```
<datepicker ng-model="dt"    datepicker-mode="'year'"
    min-mode="year"  min-date="minDate" 
    show-weeks="false" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
```

behave differently than this:

[image: popup year picker doesn't work]

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" 
         datepicker-mode="'year'"
    min-mode="year"  min-date="minDate" 
    show-weeks="false"
    datepicker-popup="{{format}}"  is-open="opened" ng-focus="open($event)"
          date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use 'datepicker-options' attribute to pass in the options, rather than the element attributes. Consider the following: http://plnkr.co/edit/FJRsvwnjitOUsGor8ZRb?p=preview

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dt" 
       datepicker-popup="{{format}}" datepicker-options="{{datepickerOptions}}"
       is-open="opened" ng-focus="open($event)"
      date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
</input>
```

and

```
$scope.datepickerOptions = {
    datepickerMode:"'year'",
    minMode:"'year'",
    minDate:"minDate",
    showWeeks:"false",
 };
```

Comment: im using ui.bootstrap 0.12.1 and angularJS 1.2.10 and i cant get it to work. and also, the example provided is not working too.